# for loop exceeding its limit

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to write playfair cipher test code, and I want to arrange the letters into a matrix format, filling the matrix diagonally from upper left corner to lower right corner. (I am considering logically that the `[0][0]` index of array corresponds to leftmost upper corner of matrix.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char key[5][5];

void gen_key(char* key_string)
{
    int i,j,k,p=0;
    if(strlen(key_string)<24)
    {
        printf("key too short\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0,k=i;j<5,k>-1;k--,j++)
        {
            key[k][j]=key_string[p++];
        }
    }
    for(j=1;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("j=%d\n",j);
        for(k=j,i=4;k<5,i>0;i--,k++)
        {
            printf("placing %c at %d %d\n",key_string[p],i,k);
            key[i][k]=key_string[p++];
        }
    }
}

void print_key()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%c ",key[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    gen_key("LQGUMDXRHBZVNEAYSICWOFTKP");
    print_key();
    return 0;
}
```

And the test output it gives is :

```
j=1
placing Y at 4 1
placing S at 3 2
placing I at 2 3
placing C at 1 4
j=2
placing W at 4 2
placing O at 3 3
placing F at 2 4
placing T at 1 5
j=3
placing K at 4 3
placing P at 3 4
placing  at 2 5
placing  at 1 6
j=4
placing  at 4 4
placing at 3 5
placing  at 2 6
placing ; at 1 7
L G D B A 
Q M H E C 
T  ; I F 
  S O P 
Y W K
```

I am not understanding why is it placing `T at 1 5` where I have mentioned that in second `for` loop the value of `k<5`.

Comment: Don't put comma expressions as a loop invariant. It's almost certainly not what you want. What condition did you mean to express with `j<5,k>-1`?

Comment: Why would you use a comma? Commas are confusing and misunderstood.

Comment: I had misunderstood that comma separated conditions in for-loop definition are treated as conjunctions :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want both conditions to be true

```
j<5,k>-1
```

use the && operator, not the comma

```
j<5 && k>-1
```

In a comma separated list, the comma yields only the last value, so in your code you were actually using only the second condition `k>-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Comma is also an operator in C, but it doesn't do what you thought it would be doing. :)

`for(j=0, k=i; j<5 && k>-1; k--, j++)` is what you need.